# Splitting user input and fill into a array with a loop (java)

Tags: java, arrays, input, split

I need to make a calculator for students grades using java. The user types in the name and score for a student on a single line separated by commas. It needs to take 10 students details. But I can not work out how to split the user input string using commas, and fill it into my array. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] student = new String[10][];

    for (int index=1; index <=10; index++){
    String userinput = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), which will return a `String[]`.

Also, arrays in Java are zero-based, so you need

```
for(int index = 0; index < student.length; index++)
```

Comment: ahhhh Thankyou, I think I just had a break through.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the loop. If you want to fill in your array, you should use the `split()` method of the `String` class, like so:

```
String userInput = scan.nextLine();
// input comma-separated grades
String[] grades  = userInput.split(",");
```

And now you have a grades array with each element as an individual grade

Comment: The array is for the 10 students.